# WPF: Composite Application with Page Navigation

Tags: wpf, navigation, composite

I am currently writing an application to which the composite methodology fits like a glove.... almost!

I also need a way to navigate between views, including maintaining a journal for navigation backward and forward.

What is the best way to combine these two methodologies, on one hand the single `Window` based CAG shell with its `UserControl` derived views, and on the other hand the convenient `NavigationWindow` shell with its `Page` derived views and journal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can display anything in a `NavigationWindow`, not just `Pages`. A simple way to make it work is to define in the `NavigationWindow`'s resources a `DataTemplate` for each ViewModel you want to display. Bind the `Content` property of the `NavigationWindow` to a property of your main ViewModel, and you're done : changing that property will update the `NavigationWindow` content, and the appropriate `DataTemplate` will be picked automatically

---

UPDATE

I just looked at the code of a project of mine where I used a `NavigationWindow`. Actually I was mistaken, it doesn't work by binding the `Content` (or maybe it works, but that's not what I did). Instead I created a `INavigationService` interface, implemented by my `App` class, which handles the navigation by calling the `NavigationWindow.Navigate` method. That way, the navigation history is maintained by the `NavigationWindow`.

Here's an extract from my project

**MainWindow.xaml :**

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel"
                  xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"
                  Title="{Binding Content.DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, FallbackValue=The Title}"
                  Height="600" Width="800">
    <NavigationWindow.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}">
            <view:HomeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
            <view:CustomerView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </NavigationWindow.Resources>
</NavigationWindow>
```

**App.xaml.cs** :

```
    ...

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadConfig();

        MyApp.MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        INavigationService navigationService = this;
        HomeViewModel viewModel = new HomeViewModel(navigationService);
        this.MainWindow = window;
        window.Navigate(viewModel);
        window.Show();
    }
```

When I need to navigate to another view, I just call the `Navigate` method with the ViewModel as a parameter, and WPF automatically picks the appropriate `DataTemplate` from the resources.

Comment: That is a nice and simple solution, but it's a little bit too simple for my taste. Issues I have with it: Journalling, view lifetime management, view states, multiple views in navigation history, `PageFunction` feature (being able to call a view in a modal fashion).

Or maybe I don't completely understand your solution, can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Another concern would be the ability to develop views in a relatively indepedent way (decoupled from the shell). Basically, you're saying I should not use CAG at all, but rather use a workaround to make a regular `NavigationWindow` feel like CAG. But then I'm losing the advantages that CAG offers, dynamic loading of modules, independent module development, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, Thomas, but I'm still not happy. What you're saying is 'create a regular navigation application, and implement the CAG parts yourself' - Meaning I need to provide for a unity container, dynamic loading of modules, dynamic creation of data templates for views, etc. I'd rather go the other way, use CAG and implement navigation and journalling myself. +1 for at least showing me what I **don't** want to do :-)

Comment: Actually I've never used CAG, and I don't know much about it. My app is just a simple MVVM app, not using any particular framework, and the technique described above works just fine, but maybe it's not adequate for CAG...